# Need Solution to integrate Node+Express+GraphQL+ApolloServer+ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql, graphql-playground

I need to develop my backed application in **NodeJS ExpressJS and GraphQL,** and I am using the Apollo GraphQL server for this. Now I have to connect this GraphQL to **ElasticSearch** so that I can directly write the ElasticSearch Queries in **Apollo Playground** like earlier I was using for GraphQL Queries.

*Can someone help me with this Scenario?*

Comment: The question appears too broad. Please attempt a solution, using standard GraphQL development procedures.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple scenarios for this through object manipulation, some use a dedicated file for elasticsearch and others use the logic directly to resolvers in graphql and then just add the main method in the graphql/nodejs server declaration in order for the initialization to start (index creation etc) (some call it index.ts it depends)

Answer (score 0):

Use objects and single responsibility.

create a frontend observable that looks at an API that API can then take data from the elastic cluster.

The problem as you pointed out is that you use graphql directly, while graphql is mainly to create a layer between front and back, what you do is making the API layer connect directly with the back, so that needs to change through a new object that only exists for the API, no matter what happens to your back this will have to stay the same, that's why graphql is important, it needs to be used on that specific way.